# OpenCV 2.4.6 on Anaconda 1.7: DLL Load failed

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I try to load the OpenCV module into Anaconda 1.7 on Windows 7SP1 x64, I get:

```
In [1]: import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Here is some diagnostic info:

```
In [2]: import platform
In [3]: platform.platform()
Out [3]: 'Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1'
In [4]: platform.architecture()
Out [4]: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE')
In [5]: !ls C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cv2.pyd
C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\cv2.pyd
In [6]: !path
PATH=C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\TextPad 5;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.8-Q16;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\IVI\bin;
C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\IVI\bin;
C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Smart Projects\IsoBuster;
C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
```

I've seen that similar questions have been asked here before, and I've attempted those solutions, and am wondering if something is different with the new Anaconda 1.7 (iPython Notebook 1.0) release.